# The hide method of Bootstrap collapse will show the collapse element

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Here is a simple example: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/FWDyV/1/)

1. click the **resize** button, making the `box div` bigger
2. click the button again, making it back to normal size. However, you will see the collapse element which should not be displayed.

I guess it's due to this line:

```js
$("div.inbox").collapse("hide");
```

The purpose of this line is: if users clicked the `a` tag to show the collapse element, when they shrink the `box div`, the collapse element will be hidden.

The weird thing is the problem only happens at the first time of clicking `resize` button. I have no idea about why it happens.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you call the collapse plugin on an element, if it has not been initialized, the init process is triggered (see [collapse.js source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/f219fee07b14ea1d37e197b1d80f5c7a8e3bc186/js/collapse.js#L168)).

By default, the init process toggles the elements (showing it if it is hidden, and hiding it if it is visible) - equivalent to `.collapse('toggle')`.

You'd need to initialize the collapsible element first, disabling the toggle-on-init parameter (see [getbootstrap.com doc](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-usage)):

```
$("div.inbox").collapse({toggle: false});
```

See example on your [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/FWDyV/2/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. By the way, in my application the `box div` is dynamically generated by `ajax`. What's the right way to initiate?

Comment: @Harrison In an ajax process it's usually after it's been created, but you should look around, someone else has certainly asked that question already

Answer (score 3):

In my scenario, I *do* want toggling after the initial hide. So I ended up using this:

```
$thingToCollapse.collapse({ 'toggle': false }).collapse('hide');
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like collapse() fires for the first time with 'show' no matter what. Simple solution is to check if .inbox is shown and if so to fire collapse('hide'). We can get the state of the element by checking if class "in" is added - .collapse = element hidden, .collapse.in = element shown

```
$("button.resize").click(function(){
    var isExpanded = !$("div.box").hasClass("expanded");
    $("div.box").toggleClass("expanded", isExpanded);
    if ($("div.inbox").hasClass("in")) {
        $("div.inbox").collapse('hide');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

After trying many tomes I've ended with:

From source https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/
 .collapse hides content
 .collapsing is applied during transitions
 .collapse.in shows content

// Hide

```
if ($('#div').hasClass("in")) {$(#div).removeClass('in');}
```

// Show

```
$('#div').addClass('in');
```

Works for me!

Answer (score 0):

$("div").collapse("show");
$("div").collapse("hide");